# Passing persistent variables/classes between Smarty functions and blocks

Tags: php, smarty

I'm defining custom blocks and functions in smarty.
Let's say my code in the template is like:

```
{myblock}
    {myfunction}
{/myblock}
```

Let's also say that `{myblock}` calls a PHP function (a static `MyClass::create()`) that creates and instance of `MyClass`.

How can I access THAT instance from the PHP code called by `{myfunction}`?

I've tried assigning the instance to a template variable, but the variable gets lost when i reference the template in `myfunction`. Same thing if I use a static property of MyClass.
Any suggestions?

(Hope it's all clear...)

Edit: Both methods called by `myblock` and `myfunction` are static, I've used a `private static $instances` variable to try to hold the instances referenced by an id, where myblock puts the instance, but no luck as for now accessing the same static variable from myfunctions, it goes empty.

Comment: You might be trying to fix things in your smarty template, which you should fix in your php-code.
The advantage of using smarty is that you separate your logic (php) from your presentation (html/smarty). Is there a reason you need to solve this in your template?

Comment: @JimmyShelter: I've always done the maximum separation between Smarty and code. In this case, however, I'm trying to build a very automated datagrid using Smarty almost only for it's parsing capabilities. My goal is to have a tool that can define a datagrid without writing any PHP code.

Comment: By datagrid I mean a real datagrid with navigation, editable fields, master/detail views. I've done this before, with pure PHP code with the goal to have a "grid definition file" to easily define all the characteristics. So, I thought, how about the inverse approach and adapt Smarty to accomplish this?